# Append value into list and make inner list

Tags: python, list

So, I have a list like

```
['sm', 'Bug Out Bag']
```

How can I make list like

```
[['sm', 'The label I entered'], ['Bug Out Bag', 'Another label I entered']]
```

where labels are entered via `input` function?

I tried this code:

```
if action_choice_perform_bag in str(bag_actions[2]):
    for b in my_bag:
        apply_label_to_front = input('What label would you like to apply to front of bag? e.g. 30.0\n')
        my_bag[b].append(apply_label_to_front)
        # print(my_bag)   contains::: ['sm', 'Bug Out Bag']
```

but it complains that in indice in `my_bag[b]` isn't an `integer`, which it isn't.

Comment: See, i wish it was that simple, but im getting an error of: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Append adds to the list. You want to create a list of lists. But you can't append to something you're iterating through. You may want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
list_of_lists = [ [b, input('What label?')] for b in my_bag ]
```

That is, use a list comprehension to make a new list, which contains lists that comprise an element from the original list, and a string from the user.

Comment: Wow, so concise, i need to get better at comprehensions. Any recommended books?

Comment: @user700070: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions, http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk, http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a few changes:

```
for item in my_bag:
    apply_label_to_front = input('What label would you like to apply to front of bag? e.g. 30.0\n')
    item.append(apply_label_to_front)
```

`my_bag` as dictionary with compression :

```
bag_names = ['sm', 'Bug Out Bag']
prompt = 'What label would you like to apply to front of bag? e.g. 30.0\n'
my_bag = {name: input(prompt) for name in bag_names}
```

Comment: Would this work if `my_bag` is a dictionary? Then `item` is a string as a key,  and there is no `str.append`

Comment: Sure. Dictionaries are there for key-value problems.